# Unioning PLSS Polygons

Tags: aggregation, plss

I want to union a set of Public Land Survey System (PLSS) polygons in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS layer, based on two fields, ‘sec_qtr’ and ‘qq’. A sample subset of polygons looks like this:

[image]

I want to select the polygons that have an identical ‘sec_qtr’ value and ‘qq’ values of ‘NE’ or ‘SE’ (i.e., the ‘East Half of the Northeast Quarter of Section 27, T1S, R1W’ in PLSS parlance). The resultant unioned geometry that I want is this:

[image]

However, the PostgreSQL script that I’m using:

```
SELECT st_union(geom) FROM work.tmp_qq1 where sec_qtr IN
(SELECT sec_qtr 
  FROM work.tmp_qq1 
  GROUP BY sec_qtr 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(sec_qtr)) > 1)
AND qq = 'NE' OR qq = 'SE';
```

gives me this result:

[image]

What do I need to change in my SQL script to get both ‘01S01W27NE’ polygons unioned together?

Comment: I would try `AND qq = 'NE' OR qq = 'SE';` -> `AND (qq = 'NE' OR qq = 'SE')` ;

Comment: No, actually that returns a null set. But any suggestions are welcome, thanks.